# How to reference Sheet name from Cell Value inside a SUMIF excel function

Tags: excel, vba

I had this case like

```
=SUMIF(SBI!C:C,"B",SBI!A:A)
```

Here SBI is the sheet name which I have hardcoded. I wanted to mention a reference to this Sheet name instead of hardcoding it.
I already have Column in current sheet which has the Sheet names mentioned in a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using VBA then you need an indirect cell reference that will contain a sheet name. E.g. in cell A1 you have the name "SBI", then the formula would be:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!C:C"),"B",INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!A:A"))
```

If you're using VBA then in the code you simply need a Worksheet variable and can use its Range properties or just concatenate a string:

```
Dim WS as Worksheet
Set WS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("SBI")

Range("A:A").Formula = ("=SUMIF('" & WS.Name & "'!C:C,""B"",'" & WS.Name & "'!A:A)")
```

The reason I'm putting ' quote marks around any sheet name is in case a sheet name has a space in it E.g. `Sheet2!A:A` will work but `Sheet 2!A:A` will not... you should always put worksheet names in quotes for safety and future-proofing :D `'Sheet 2'!A:A`

Comment: thanks, was missing those extra quotes. Had tried this but repeated errors made me query here.

Comment: No problems, it's something I spent at least 30 minutes on once being very confused, but that's how we learn!? :D